# upgrade kernel using terminal in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-one, kernel

Is there any possibility to upgrade the kernel by using command in terminal in ubuntu? 
If yes, then please reply. Please tell if possible that how command works?
thanks

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here. Do you want to upgrade to the last vanilla kernel or just to the last distribution kernel?.

Comment: I have not more info about this but it may be distribution kernel

Comment: Can you give us some context?. To wich kernel do you want to update to?. Why?. Your kernel should be updated the same way that the rest of the system.

Answer (score 2):

run the following code:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upgrade the kernal of Ubuntu 11.10 which is in my system linux-image 3.0.0.17 to linux-image 3.2.x.x then I think 3.2.x.x is not available for Ubuntu 11.10.

If you want to do that forcefully then here what you can do:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:francisbrwn9/kernels
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

http://www.unixmen.com/how-to-upgrade-to-kernel-3-2-in-ubuntu11-10-and-linuxmint12/